# How to Retrieve Sub Collection in firestore firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Project which have a structure like this

```
CollectionReference adminList;
adminList = mFirestore.collection("AdminList");
            Map<String,Object> k = new HashMap<>();
            k.put("order",order);
            k.put("status","New Order");
            k.put("hotel_name",username.getText().toString());
            k.put("user_id",mUid);
            k.put("time", "Select Time");
            //adminList.document(order).set(k);
            adminList.document(mUid).collection("User").document(order).set(k);
```

There Can be Multiple Users with their UserId. I have to retrieve it in the list.

To do so, I used the following code.

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mFirestore.collection("AdminList").getParent().collection("Users").addSnapshotListener(MainActivity.this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            orderList.clear();
            assert queryDocumentSnapshots != null;
            List<OrderList> types = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(OrderList.class);
            orderList.addAll(types);

            adapter = new AdminListAdapter(MainActivity.this,orderList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });

}
```

but I need a way to access the sub collection and its document so that I can retrieve the list in my recyclerview.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please add your database structure and indicate which values you want to get and you want to be added in an ArrayList?

Comment: I've uploaded the Screenshot please see

Comment: That's good but please indicate which values you want to get and you want to be added in an ArrayList? `hotel_name`, `order` and so on, that's right?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:-

```
firestore.collection("AdminList").document(mUid).collection("User").document(order).addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e)
            {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists())
                {
                  types = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(OrderList.class);
                  orderList.addAll(types);
                 }
             });
```